# How to disable, blur, cover etc. a screenshot taken in a hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, screenshot, hybrid-mobile-app

What is the right way to prevent a screenshot being taken of your app view and saved on the phone, using AngularJS, Phonegap, Cordova and or Javascript or other Hybrid technologies?

It can be especially problematic with the iOS multi task view, as it takes a screenshot automatically.

I was thinking of either capturing the screenshot somehow (cordova plugin?) and transforming it (low quality, blurring), or just somehow disabling it.

How do you do that or are there other methods?